# Customizing Python IDLE: how do I get tabs and a file browser?

Tags: python, notepad++, ide, extension

Are there any extensions to add tabs and a file browser to IDLE? I mean [this kind of tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(interface)), not the "\t" kind of tab. What I want is Notepad++'s "Folder as Workspace" feature and tab feature in IDLE. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IDLEx extension](http://idlex.sourceforge.net/features.html)  provides tabbed editor windows with drag'n'drop reordering, and [works with both 2.7 and 3.x Python](https://github.com/serwy/idlex/blob/master/README.md). There are [quite a few file managers for Python](https://github.com/topics/file-manager?l=python) (and [another](https://www.giuspen.com/nautilus-pyextensions/)), depending on your OS and desktop.

Comment: I like IDLEx. Thank you for showing me.